# I need to get average document count by date in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I want to get average document count by date without getting the whole bunch of buckets data and get average value by hand cause there are years of data and when I group by the date I get `too_many_buckets_exception`.
So my current query is

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [],
      "filter": []
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "groupByChannle": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "channel"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "docs_per_day": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "message_date",
            "fixed_interval": "1d"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I get an average doc count grouped by message_date(day) and channel without taking buckets array of this data

```
"buckets" : [
              {
                "key_as_string" : "2018-03-17 00:00:00",
                "key" : 1521244800000,
                "doc_count" : 4027
              },
              {
                "key_as_string" : "2018-03-18 00:00:00",
                "key" : 1521331200000,
                "doc_count" : 10133
              },
...thousands of rows
]
```

my index structure looks like this

```
  "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "channel" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        }, 
        "message" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "message_date" : {
          "type" : "date",
          "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        },
      }
    }
```

By this query, I want to get JUST A AVERAGE DOC COUNT BY DATE and nothing else

Answer (score 2):

```
"avg_count": {
  "avg_bucket": {
    "buckets_path": "docs_per_day>_count"
  }
}
```

after `docs_per_day` ending this.

`avg_count` provides average count.
`_count` refers the bucket count

Comment: Thanks for the answer, provided code works and it getting avg count but my problem is that I don't want to get bucket data too cause it is very big I just want to get an average count

Comment: Sorry to be such a late :( I have upvoted the answer but as my reputation is under 15 it's not visible yet.
But I can't accept the answer cause it does not fulfill all my requirements (maybe I have not explained very well my main goal)

I don't want to fetch buckets array too cause there are thousands of rows and I want to get average daily doc count without grouping them and fetching this buckets data I want to get JUST A AVERAGE DOC COUNT and nothing else.
  "avg_bucket": {
    "buckets_path": "docs_per_day>_count"
  }
this thing only works if I will aggregate data by date.

Answer (score 1):

I think, that you can use stats aggregation with the script :

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "term": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "chanel"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "stats": {
          "stats": {
            "field": "message_date"
          }
        },
        "result": {
          "bucket_script": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "max" : "stats.max",
              "min" : "stats.min",
              "count" : "stats.count"
            },
            "script": "params.count/(params.max - params.min)/1000/86400)"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```